# File is not readable for excel reader in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Recently I use Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader for reading a .xls file in codeigniter. I have done the following step :

1. paste the Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader in system/application/libraries.
2. change error_reporting in your index.php to error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
3. Then write the following code in my controller :

   ```
   $pathToFile = base_url().'uploads/loop.xls';
   $params = array('file' => $pathToFile, 'store_extended_info' => true);

   $this->load->library('Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader', $params);
   $data['xlsFile'] = $this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->dump(false, false, 0, 'excel');
   $this->load->view('test.php', $data);
   ```

But the problem was this show the following error :

```
   The filename http://www.example.com/uploads/loop.xls is not readable.
```

Here the file location is correct. The file is also in .xls format. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that **allow_url_fopen** is set to on in php.ini.

May be using the real path instead of url can be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a problem with the file permissions, it should be read/write for webserver

Answer (score 0):

> Please use FCPATH.'uploads/loop.xls';  ( whatever Your file path )
>
> its working for me, you can try this.

Answer (score -1):

Please try change:

```
$pathToFile = base_url().'uploads/loop.xls';
```

to:

```
$pathToFile = './uploads/loop.xls';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your excel file won't be readable due to following causes---

1.) You don't have original Microsoft Office
2.) Your extension may be incorrect.

Solution->

Uninstall your pirated Office and install kingsoft or libre office than your excel will definately work.